# how to not display power of E when the number is big on a jTable row?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double, number-formatting

Im making a small accounting program. Then my problem is when displaying a big number on a jTable.

I use `SELECT` method from the data base, then convert the ResultSet into TableModel then set it into the jTable. The problem lies when displaying big numbers (ie 10.000.000 it will display 1.0E7 on the jTable) is there a way to keep the original format (10000000) instead of 1.0E7?

By the way I used Double type for the element type.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table model overrides `getColumnClass()` and returns the appropriate type for your column (`Double.class`).

This will make the table use a DecimalFormat with the default locale to format the numbers, rather than calling `toString()`.

Side note: using double for money, especially for big amounts, is a really bad idea. You should use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: This is a much better and more relevant answer than mine. Fools rush in ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says 1.0E7 is because that's the precision offered by the number format being used. It's a more scientific way of saying "About 10,000,000 rows".

Do you really want to provide an almost definitely wrong value in the hundreds, tens and units columns over a precise estimate that declares the limits of its resolution?